# Android tabs sorting listview not updating

Tags: android, listview

I have a program which has tabs. Each of these tab contains the same listview from the database, but ordered differently. When I delete the code on 1 tab, it deletes from the database, but does not delete on the other tab.

Tabs:

> by Date | By Name

Here is the code:

Tab.java:

```
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");

    // Set the Tab name and Activity
    // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected
    tab1.setIndicator("By Date ↓");


    Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.example.user.test.ALPHABETICAL");
    intent1.putExtra("record", value);
    intent1.putExtra("name", name);
    intent1.putExtra("id", id);
    intent1.putExtra("alpha", alpha);
    tab1.setContent(intent1);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.example.user.test.LISTRECORD");
    intent2.putExtra("record", value);
    intent2.putExtra("name", name);
    intent2.putExtra("id", id);
    tab2.setContent(intent2);
```

alpha is the array sorted alphabetically, value is by recently added.

This is one of the listview code:

```
    value=(ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("record");
    name=(ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("name");
    id=(ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("id");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, value);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

As I said before, the tabs are not updating, even though they are feeding from the same database.

Comment: are you calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after deleting the database?

Comment: Hi, tried that, but keep in mind that the adapters are different for each listview. It doesn't change one.

Comment: You still have to manage each listview. The thing with Tabs is that the system renders them only once, depending the size and current position. Normally it will render up to one or two views ahead, so the view is ready when the user scrolls to it. So it makes sense that if you have three of them, they will only get rendered once, adapters are not constantly watching for changes in the DB, you have to tell them to update accordingly. If you share more relevant code I will be able to help further

Comment: Hi, this is the only relevant code I have. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not with this little code. Sorry.